# why http://server:60010 web page for the running HBase Master

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I installed by :

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hbase-0.90.3-cdh3u1.tar.gz
```

This is my hbase_site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>localhost:60000</value>
    <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.A value of 'local' runs the master and a regionserver in a single process.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hdfs</value>
    <description>The directory shared by region servers.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed  Zookeeper true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)
    </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2183</value>
    <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.The port at which the clients will connect.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
    <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.For example,"host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com".By default this is set to localhost for local and pseudo-distributed modes of operation. For afully-distributed setup, this should be set to a full list of ZooKeeper quorum servers. If HBASE_MANAGES_ZK is set in hbase-env.sh this is the list of servers which we will start/stop ZooKeeper on. </description>
</property>
```

hbase-env.h

```
# Tell HBase whether it should manage it's own instance of Zookeeper or not.
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false

Here we are running our separate Zookeeper so needs to specify false. Default Hbase starts the default zookeeper compes up with Hbase.

#JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

and when m starting hbase

```
<HBASE_HOME>/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

and try to open http://server:60010 it is not opening ?

why ?

Comment: problem was that zookeeper was not started

Answer (score 1):

From the comments - this problem was caused because zookeeper was not running.

Answer (score 1):

First check "**hbase-hduser-master-ubuntu.log**" file from **logs** folder of your hbase installed path

**if you are getting following error**

2014-09-07 20:22:24,505 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting java.lang.RuntimeException: **HMaster Aborted at** org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:194) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135) at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2794)

compare **core-site.xml** of ***Hadoop*** with **hbase-site.xml** of ***hbase***. hdfs URL should be same in both file

***core-site.xml***

```
 <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.203.130:9000</value>
    </property>
 </configuration>
```

***hbase-site.xml***

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <!-- <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value> -->
    <value>hdfs://192.168.203.130:9000/hbase</value> 
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "hadoop-core-*.jar" from your `HADOOP_HOME` and "commons-configuration-*.jar" from your `HADOOP_HOME/lib` into the `HBASE_HOME/lib` folder.Also edit the "hosts" file and replace "127.0.1.1" with "127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

Download from this source and follow the process:

```
wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hbase/stable/hbase-1.2.4-bin.tar.gz

tar xvzf hbase-1.2.4-bin.tar.gz
```

After untar use sudo mv command to move file to your deserved`enter code here` location mine is:

```
 sudo mv hbase-1.2.4 /*path of untar file*/ /usr/local/hbase/
```